# Where does eclipse store the settings of the *Externalize Strings* dialog?

Tags: java, eclipse

Where does eclipse store the settings of the *Externalize Strings* dialog?

(**Edit**: I am not talking about the properties file which holds the strings `Foo_0=foo`, ..., but the settings of the dialog itself.)

In particular there is a combo box *Accessor class* which has a *Configure...* button next to it. I tried to delete some of its entries, but could find no configuration page or similar.

[image]

Comment: Eclipse saves it's settings AFAIK either in `eclipse/configuration` or within the workspace (`workspace/.metadata`, `workspace/project/.settings`)

Comment: @zapl *somewhere* there, but OP asks for *exact* location

Comment: That combo box I think is a calculated value derived from analyzing the project so, it cannot be configured. You just have to pick one

Comment: @shyam I disagree, because it remembered old (and wrong) settings I put into it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find what you are looking for here:

```
<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring/dialog_settings.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

In my Eclipse Photon the data is stored in

`<workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.ui\dialog_settings.xml`

You find it in the section named "nls_accessor_history"